# Limiting line length in Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor, pep8

I've been trying to get my line length hard limited to 80 characters in Atom. I have found in the setting the "max screen line length" but I cannot set a value there. I've set the soft wrap but this doesn't seem to work either. I checked packages and nothing from a specific language is driving it either. I found the [autoflow](https://github.com/atom/autoflow) package but it doesn't give a clear indication of how to drive it to 80 characters. Any advice on how to implement this would be helpful. I understand that 80 characters is the PEP 8 standard and I don't want to start off with issues.

Answer (score 24):

> I have found in the setting the "max screen line length" but I cannot set a value there.

The correct setting to set is the **Preferred Line Length**.
It is part of the same *Settings* > *Editor* page where you found **Max Screen Line Length**.

[image: screenshot for Preferred Line Length]

As indicated in the description of **Preferred Line Length**, you also need to enable the **Soft Wrap At Preferred Line Length** (still part of the *Settings* > *Editor* page). And in the description of **Soft Wrap At Preferred Line Length**, it says that you also need to enable the main **Soft Wrap** setting (still part of the *Settings* > *Editor* page).

Good thing is they are conveniently placed next to each other.
Enable them both:

[image: screenshot for soft wrap]

That takes care of the default Atom editor settings.

Since you mentioned PEP8, make sure you also set the same settings on the pre-included **language-python** package (*Settings* > *Packages*, search for "language-python").

[image: screenshot for language-python]

With all those settings, Atom should now automatically wrap long texts into a newline when it exceeds 80 characters. (You can set the character limit to anything actually, ex. 160. Just make sure to set the same **Preferred Line Length** for both Atom's and language-python's settings.)

Comment: I know how to convert soft wrap into hard wrap by using hard-wrap package. But do you know how to convert it back? Is there any package help us to automatically manage each line?

Comment: @skytree I am not sure I understand what you mean.. but it seems you want to toggle the wrapping style on a line-by-line basis. I am not aware of any such package, since I always apply soft-wrapping on ALL lines at once. I suggest you post a new question here in SO for that.